# LUBUNTU 14.04 and fcitx-qimpanel : How to remove this BLACK SQUARE

Tags: lubuntu, fcitx

Now that **FCITX-QIMPANEL** is properly installed on my **LUBUNTU 14.04** (see this problem on askubuntu [Installing SOGOU 搜狗拼音](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450255/sogou-linux-for-lubuntu-14-04)) I still have a small problem :

How to remove this black square that appears near my cursor (where the input method rectangle appears when I'm typing) ?

If you have any idea, thank you for your suggestions.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Aron Xu on launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fcitx/+bug/1309841) Lubuntu has no compositing window manager by default, that's why openbox didn't know how to deal with transparency.

So here is the solution to deal with this problem :

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:richardgv/compton`
- `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install compton`
- Then follow this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144468, but with `shadow = false;`
- Restart, and that's it ! No more black square.