# ubuntu install "sogou pinyin" doesn't work

Tags: chinese, pinyin

after successful downloading the sogou pinyin deb I install by double click and it shows sucessfully installed but cannot start. My system is ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. What is "sogou pinyin"? Where did you get it? What is it supposed to do? Please elaborate, a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Sogoupinyin is a Chinese input method very popular in China. The linux version of the software is available here: http://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/ .

If you have been messing with your Ubuntu you may want to follow the installation instructions outlined in [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450255/installing-sogou-%E6%90%9C%E7%8B%97%E6%8B%BC%E9%9F%B3) 
on askubuntu.com.

This worked for me on a clean Ubuntu install:

1. Install fcitx.
   Fcitx is an input method framework. Linux' sogoupinyin is based on fcitx, so we have to make sure it is installed. You can do so by firing up a terminal with `SHIFT + ALT + T` and typing:

   > sudo apt-get update
   >   sudo apt-get install fcitx

   This should run on its own. After installation is complete, your system uses fcitx as input method. To check if it does, go to `language support` and check the entry `Keyboard input method system`. It should now say `fcitx`.
2. Install Sogoupinyin.
   Then run the installer file sogoupinyin_xxxxx.deb that you have downloaded from the Sogou website. It will open the Software Center of your Ubuntu installation and ask for your root password.
3. Restart your machine.
   You are good to go. After the restart the `fcitx-autostart` should be called upon login. Alternatively, simply run `fcitx-autostart` from the terminal with the same effect, but give it a second or two for the startup. You will then be able to configure sogoupinyin in a way similar to the Windows or Mac versions of the software.

Hope it helps.

Comment: On 18.04: `Settings` > `Region & Language` > `Manage installed Languages` > `Keyboard input method system` should be `fcitx`

Answer (score 1):

u.Hi, basically you need to add ppa:fcitx-team/nightly,
then update fcitx in your linux distro, last install the deb package downloaded from official website. If you see a black box when switching to sogou pinyin input, you will need to install xcompmgr as well, and make it auto start. 
I have include a thorough guide in my blog, you are welcome to check it out and leave comments if it doesn't work for you.

http://www.qiweihuang.com/installing-sogou-pinyin-in-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 1):

This blog solved my installation http://cherishlc.iteye.com/blog/2320166.

All the other places don't mention "Only show current language" needs to be unticked.

Comment: On Askubuntu, you should write a small instruction, and use the link only as source.