# Typing chinse pinyin is borked

Tags: input-method, chinese

So in chinse, the phrase "How are you?" in pinyin is:

> nihaoma?

However, when I try to enter it in, I get this:
[image]
And the words are broken. Also, the text "so" is:

> zheme

However, it comes out as:
[image]

Why is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default pinyin in Ubuntu does have this quirk. I personally use Sun pyinyin or Intelligent pinyin.

You can get both with `sudo apt-get install ibus-libpinyin ibus-sunpinyin`. Once downloaded, add those in the <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Region & Language</kbd> -> <kbd>Input Sources</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

How your system handles pinyin input largely depends on the system input method. From your pictures I am unable to figure out which one you use. Is it sunpinyin?

Have you considered installing Sogou Pinyin? Sogou has no problem handling the phrases nihaoma and zheme -- I have just checked it on my system.

I have posted instructions on how to install Sogou Pinyin on an Ubuntu machine [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606148/ubuntu-install-sogou-pinyin-doesnt-work/659647#659647)