# Prevent fcitx autostart

Tags: input-method, chinese, pinyin

I would like to prevent the fcitx input method selection tool from starting automatically.

I have an up-and-running `fcitx` with Chinese `sogoupinyin` installed on my system. If I restart the computer `fcitx-autostart` automatically loads the qimpanel for input method selection. All that works just fine; and there are two posts on askubuntu that outline the installation: 
[one here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/606148/ubuntu-install-sogou-pinyin-doesnt-work) 
and [a second one here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450255/installing-sogou-%E6%90%9C%E7%8B%97%E6%8B%BC%E9%9F%B3).

However, I do not want `fcitx` to start automatically.
This is because I am running Ubuntu on a rather old computer and hardware resources are limited. The fcitx startup also adds about two seconds to my booting time. Third, I don't always use the Chinese input, but sometimes. If I want to use Chinese input I am happy to run `fcitx-autostart` from a terminal.

So my question is: How do I prevent the `fcitx` autostart?

---

I have googled this question and stumbled upon this post:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2227101
They mention their solution was to remove the file `22_fcitx.rc` from `/usr/share/im-config/data/`, but that has not worked for me.

---

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Open Language Support and select "none" as the "Keyboard input method system". However, then, if you want to use fcitx for inputting, you need to switch it back to fcitx and relogin.

Comment: Your solution works as far as disabling fcitx is concerned. The selection menu qimpanel, however, still autostarts. Also, changing settings and logging back in is too much effort if I do want to use fcitx

Comment: @flobo93: I fully understand the latter. Sorry but I have no sensible solution to suggest which would satisfy your whole spec. (Removing a file belonging to the im-config package would just be a bad hack.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. As you can I am new to Ubuntu and wasn't sure if manipulating the package files is good practice or not.

Answer (score 1):

run

gome-session-properties

uncheck fcitx autostart