# The sougou Chinese input does not work suddenly

Tags: language-support, chinese, pinyin

I installed Sougou chinese pinying input long time ago, and it keeps working for a long time (more than years). Recently, it suddenly encounters a problem and I could not get any Chinese Characters any more.

When the system is on Sougou status, I tried to type something, and takes the picture using my phone（The first picture [image: Picture when typing Chinese pinyin for **Shuju**]）. When click `space`, it only results in `Shuju` instead of Chinese Characters.

I also show another two screenshots when it is in [image: English input] and [image: Sougou input].

My system is Ubuntu 1404. Anyone has similar issues and solutions? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? Check out [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/451063/606758) for performing re-installation. The first step may not apply to you if you did not use a PPA. If you did, you might want to figure out how to remove it. That first step does not look like the command to actually perform removal.

Comment: Take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/450255/installing-sogou-%E6%90%9C%E7%8B%97%E6%8B%BC%E9%9F%B3

Comment: Thanks. I reinstalled all and followed the given link. It works.